# Discussion Board data missing in column

Tags: column, discussion-board

On a SharePoint 2013 intranet, I created a discussion with "Created By" being one of the column.

The column is to show the Office, users are from. The office is displayed for some users while being blank for others. If I change the field to show name instead of office, it will show the name for every user.

I looked at their profiles on the SharePoint Server and the Office field has data. The same thing happens on another discussion board with the same field and users.

Comment: I also changed the Created By field to Separtment and the same users are showing blank data even though this field has data in their SharePoint profile.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint wasn't set up to update user data through Active Directory. I set it up to do that and it solved the issue.